# Bootstrap - I am not able to split the container in to columns by calculating by 12

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I do have a div, I need to make 2 colum in that, one should have divided by another 4 sub colums, and the another column should be full width.

I tried this way, but not result, anyone help me?

[Bootstrap Fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/132557)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ce4mq/)

my html and css:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col1">
        <div class="col-sm-3">3 of 12 width</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">2 of 12 width</div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">3 of 12 width</div>
        <div class="col-sm-5">4 of 12 width</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col2">
        <div class="col-sm-12">12 of 12 width</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.row{
    border:2px dotted gray;
}

.col1{
    border:1px solid green;
}

.col2{
    border:1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what your question is but I've amended your code a little bit to make it inline with Bootstrap's rules: http://jsfiddle.net/Ce4mq/2/

Comment: Actually I am looking for the first column will divided by 4 pieces (column) but your fiddle fails.

Comment: do you expect them under each other ?

Comment: try this [bootstrap fiddle editor](http://www.bootply.com/132557) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should surround your row by a container

> Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.

Then use row to divide your sub column like

```
 row
   col-6
     row
       col-3
       col-2 ...etc
```

Hope it helps

Oh, hum, try it in a simple web page (not jsFidle) on your computer. JSFidle wasn't working so well for me, so maybe it does not handle bootstrap code so well...

edit: thanks to dwza, I test this

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <!-- your first col -->
    <div class="col-sm-6 col1">
        <!-- your row inside the col -->
        <div class="row">
            <!-- your subcol inside the col -->
            <div class="col-sm-6">6 of 12 width</div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">6 of 12 width</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col2">
        <div>12 of 12 width</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

on http://www.bootply.com/ and it seems to work ;)

Answer (score 0):

The

```
<div class="row">
```

needs to be inside of a

```
<div class="container">
```

Comment: It's not going to work in the fiddle, you aren't including all of the Bootstrap CSS there.